Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{z/n}-1}{\sqrt n}$

Convergence set of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{z/n}-1}{\sqrt n}$$
and study where the sum $f(z)$ is an holomorphic function.


(1) I notice that for $n\to \infty$
$$e^{z/n}-1\sim \frac{z}{n}$$
so the general term is asymptotic to
$$a_n = \frac{z}{n^{3/2}}$$
general term of a convergent series $\forall z \in \Bbb C$, so I think I can conclude that the radius of convergence is $R=\infty$

(2) For the second part I think that I should verify that the convergence is uniform in every compact subset so let $K\subseteq \Bbb C$ compact. So exist a $d \in \Bbb R$ such that $|z|\leq d, \forall z \in K $ and then for $n\to \infty$
$$\bigg | \frac{e^{z/n}-1}{\sqrt n}\bigg| \leq c  \frac{d}{n^{3/2}}$$
confirming that the convergence is uniform hence $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C$

I think that I'm missing something or maybe I'm totally wrong about this. In this kind of exercises I struggle a bit. For example here I was trying so hard to not use asymptotic but I wasn't able to think of something else.
Thank you for the help!

You can make it a little more rigorous but the idea is the same. Let $K$ be a compact disk. Since the function $\frac{e^z-1}z$ is entire, and in particular it is continuous, it must be bounded on the compact set $K$, say $\leq M$. Note that $z/n$ belongs to $K$ if $z$ belongs to $K$, because $K$ is a disk. We thus have $$\left|\frac{e^{z/n}-1}{z/n}\right|\leq M$$ which implies $$\left|\frac{e^{z/n}-1}{\sqrt n}\right|\leq\frac{M|z|}{n\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{MR}{n\sqrt{n}}$$ where $R$ is the radius of $K$. Now the sum of $$\frac{MR}{n\sqrt n}$$ converges and Weierstrass M test implies that the sum converges uniformly on $K$.

Nice answer but your profile pic is upside down

No. What makes you think it is upside down?

Why do you consider the function $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ and not simply $e^z-1$?

We need the extra $n$ in the denominator, which we wouldn't get if we chose $e^z-1$. Note that the sum of $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ does not converge.

@spinosarus123 well your eyes are below your mouth and nose.
